# Will increasing timecost , memorycost , parallelism in argon2ID increase security in general?

Tags: hash, key-derivation, password-hashing, argon2

currently I am using parameters for argon2ID in terms of timecost , memorycost , parallelism higher than what is recommended in RFC9106 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9106.html for increased security, the parameters i use are :-

Timecost=12
Memorycost=2097152
parallelism=4

will this result in increased security or reduction in security?

Comment: In the politest way possible, I would encourage you to search this site and the web for answers to questions like this. Some of your questions so far have been duplicates, and chances are you will learn a lot more from independent reading than asking very specific questions.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 really sorry, i would avoid asking duplicate question and do more independent reading as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does increase security but slows down the login system.